# Does boost::io_service::post queue request?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm using `boost::io_service` as follows.

```
boost::io_service service;
service.post(boost::bind(...));
service.post(boost::bind(...));
service.post(boost::bind(...));
```

I want to understand if post is queuing my request, guaranteeing order of execution or can request be dropped. I've searched the boost documentation for the answer without luck.

Comment: No, the order of execution is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Chad That's good news, does that suggest that my request will never get dropped?

Comment: The callbacks will be called at the appropriate time as long as the underlying `io_service` is being polled (via `run()`, `poll()`, `run_one()` or `poll_one()`) by some thread.

Comment: "is being polled" So that would mean its queued and if call `poll_one()` three times all three request will fire off assuming they are not infinite loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the order of execution is not guaranteed by default.

When a callback is posted to an `io_service`, that callback will be called at "the appropriate time" as long as the underlying `io_service` is being actively polled by some thread (using one of the following functions: `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()`, `poll_one()`).

Some commands that can be posted may not ever return (such as an asynchronous read on a socket, where no data is ever sent).  These types of asynchronous actions usually will provide an error code to the callback that can be checked.  This error code in certain cases will give details about the success (or failure) of an operation.  In the cited example above, pending asynchronous reads will have their callbacks executed with the error code "operation aborted" if the underlying socket is closed.

Comment: So that would mean its queued and if I call `poll_one()` three times all three request will fire off assuming they are not infinite loops.

Comment: @andre: With no guaranteed order of execution, the three posted handlers are guaranteed to be invoked if `poll_one()` is invoked three times, the handlers return (no infinite loop), and the handlers do not post more handlers into the `io_service`.